# What can I say about the Parikh map of a CSL?

Tags: fl.formal-languages, automata-theory

Write $\Psi$ as the [Parikh map](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/courses/CS9620b/parikh.pdf)--i.e., $\Psi(w) = \{(\#_\sigma(w))_{\sigma\in \Sigma}\vert w\in L\}$, where $\#_\sigma(w)$ is the number of times $\sigma$ appears in $w$. It's well-known that, for a CFL $L$, $\Psi(L)$ is a semilinear set (this is Parikh's theorem). Some other interesting things are known, but I have found nothing about the Parikh map of a context-sensitive language. In particular,

> what can I say about $\Psi(L_2 - L_1)$
>   or $\Psi(\bar{L}_1)$ if $L_1, L_2$ are
>   context-free? For instance, if I let
>   $\phi(L) = \{\sum_\sigma \#_\sigma(w)\vert w\in L\} = \{|w|
>  \vert w\in L\}$, is it possible that
>   there is a CFL $L$ such that
>   $\phi(\bar{L}) = \{n!\vert n\in
>  \mathbb{N}\}$? (or any other
>   'increasing' sequence converging in
>   $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$, for that matter.)

Comment: @alpoge: Would you mind to explain the notations you used? For example, what is $\#_\sigma(w)$? And maybe some links to the terms like "Parikh's theorem" will help, too.

Comment: $\#_\sigma(w)$ is the number of times $\sigma$ appears as a letter in $w$.

Comment: FWIW, the second part should be false, as CFLs are closed under morphisms and $\{1^{n!} \;|\; n \in N\}$ is not CF.

Comment: Wait--I should probably have chosen a better letter, but that's the image of a coCFL, $\bar{L}$. (I think I'm probably missing something though.)

Comment: Oh, sorry, the math font is rubbish on my computer, and I didn't see the complementing.

Comment: But as every CFL over a unary alphabet is regular (and, hence, every coCFL over a unary alphabet), that's not a problem.

Comment: Sure--in that case, anyway, $L_2 - L_1$ would be regular anyway, so $\Psi(L_2 - L_1)$ would be semilinear, which indeed gives the contradiction. However, if we're working with $|\Sigma|\geq 2$, I don't see why the homomorphism taking everything to $1$ should take coCFLs to coCFLs.

Comment: Of course, you are right. My mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the second part of your question: If you choose your CFL $L$ to be the set of all invalid computations of a Turing machine $M$ (see, e.g., Chapter 8.6 in the first edition of "Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation"), $\phi(\overline{L})$ is the set of all lengths of encodings of accepting computations of $M$.

Although this does not directly answer your question, you can use this approach to construct quite complicated sets.

Comment: Yep!--I was thinking about that as well. I actually think this may be where a counterexample to what I'm trying to prove arises, but I haven't quite thought enough about it (unfortunately!).